# Regex to filter span tag if it having attribute

Tags: java, regex

I have below code where i want to strip or remove span tag if it is not having any attributes using java.

This regex removes all SPAN tags. <(/)?[ ]*span[^>]*>

e.g.

```
<span style="font-weight: bold;text-decoration-line: underline;">test</span><p><span>&nbsp;</span></p><p><span>Table</span></p>
```

output:

```
  <span style="font-weight: bold;text-decoration-line: underline;">test</span><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Table</p>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. A regular expression can't know which closing `</span>` tag belongs to the `<span>` you want to remove. Use a HTML parser such as [jsoup](https://jsoup.org).

Edit:

## Example

```
    String html = "<span style=\"font-weight: bold;text-decoration-line: underline;\">test</span><p><span>&nbsp;</span></p><p><span>Table</span></p>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    for (Element span : doc.getElementsByTag("span")) {
        if (span.attributes().size() == 0) {
            span.unwrap();
        }
    }

    doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);

    String result = doc.body().html();
```

Comment: Do we have sample to achieve this?

Comment: @Kalpesh Added an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. One followup question. 
Output of this is arranged in like below: <span style="font-weight: bold;text-decoration-line: underline;">test</span>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Table</p>  , on separate line. Can this be in single line?

Comment: You can disable the formatting in the output settings of the document: `doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);`

Answer (score -1):

Try this in java code

```
var str = // your string here

str = str.replaceAll("<\\/span[^>]*>", "");
```

Comment: str = str.replace(/<\/?span[^>]*>/g,"");         try this

Comment: https://regex101.com/  try on this website first <\/span[^>]*> use this

Comment: This won't work. It will remove all closing `</span>` tags, even the ones that belong to the opening tags that aren't removed.

Comment: In website you provided if i put this in regular expression, <\/span[^>]*> it is not matching anything.

Comment: @Kalpesh  str = str.replaceAll("<\\/span[^>]*>", "");